# Unable to request a controller method

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp

I am requesting for a controller method through jsp page.I am using button,link and spring tags but nothing is working.
I am getting this error while clicking the button.

```
Mar 06, 2021 8:40:46 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI 
[/Reservation/reservation/reservation/getReservationList] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
```

My jsp page is as below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %> 
<html>  
<body>  
<p>Your reservation is confirmed successfully. Please, re-check the details.</p>  
 First Name : ${reservation.firstName} <br>  
 Last Name : ${reservation.lastName}  
 <input type="button" value="bh" onclick="reservation/getReservationList">
 <input type="button"  onclick="location.href='/getReservationList'" value="Register" >
 <form:form method="GET" commandName="reservation/getReservationList">
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
 </form:form>
 </body>  
 </html>
```

As above I am using different ways to access 'reservation/getReservationList' but nothing is working.

My controller is,

```
package com.srinath.controller;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;  
 import org.springframework.ui.Model;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

    import com.srinath.model.Reservation;
import com.srinath.service.InterceptorService;  

 @RequestMapping("/reservation")  
 @Controller  
 public class ReservationController { 
 @Autowired
 private InterceptorService service;


  public InterceptorService getService() {
    return service;
  }
  public void setService(InterceptorService service) {
    this.service = service;
  }
  @RequestMapping("/bookingForm")  
  public String bookingForm(Model model)  
   {  
  //create a reservation object   
  Reservation res=new Reservation();  
  //provide reservation object to the model   
  model.addAttribute("reservation", res);  
   return "reservation-page";  
  }  
 @RequestMapping("/submitForm")  
 // @ModelAttribute binds form data to the object  
 public String submitForm(@ModelAttribute("reservation") Reservation res)  
 {  
 System.out.println(res.getFirstName()+" "+res.getLastName());
 service.Insert(res);
 return "confirmation-form";  
  }  
@RequestMapping("/getReservationList")  
//@ModelAttribute binds form data to the object  
public List<Reservation> getReservationList()  
{  
List<Reservation> rlist=service.showResults();
return rlist;  
} 
}
```

The methods bookingForm and submitForm are working fine.But unable to call getReservationList method.

Answer (score 0):

The pageContext is one of the 11 implicit objects in java JSP which is used to get context path of the application.

${pageContext.request.contextPath}/...

You can leverage this to achieve you requirement.

Let me know if I can help you further.

Comment: i have removed slash for button now it is working  <input type="button"  onclick="location.href='getReservationList'" value="Register" >

Comment: Ok..but have a look at pageContext it's much more recommend.